# sexual assault, intoxication, consent

Tags: criminal-law, sexual-assault, equal-protection

[This question/answer did not quite satisfy my curiosity](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/17646/if-two-individuals-who-are-too-drunk-to-give-consent-have-sex-are-both-guilty-of).

Let's assume this is about heterosexual sex. In a society with law that does not discriminate with respect to gender, if both a woman and man are intoxicated and both apparently give consent to sex, does the law hold either accountable for criminal culpability for sexual assault?

I understand that an intoxicated adult's consent to sex is not considered legally sufficient for responsible consent.  If one person was not intoxicated and the other was, consent was given, sex occurred, and then later the previously intoxicated person had regrets, I can sorta see the basis for a criminal prosecution of the non-intoxicated person for manipulating this drunk person into a sex act when they would not otherwise consent.

Also, in most criminal acts, for the perpetrator to be drunk when they commit a crime *might* **mitigate** culpability, but intoxication of the perp does not **eliminate** culpability.  I imagine that a drunk person who robs a bank or mugs another person or assaults another person (whether it's sexual assault or not) is still held culpable for the crime even though they were drunk.

So the adult guy is drunk or stoned, the adult lady is also drunk or stoned.  Both say "yes" to each other and do the horizontal bop.  No force, no injury, no torn clothes.

Then 12 hours later one of them decides they were raped.  **Insists** they were raped.  Says that they were not in sufficient condition to give consent.  Is the other legally liable?  How is it decided?  What conditions must be met to hold one as the perpetrator and the other as the victim?  By being first to cry *"rape!"*, does that make the other the perpetrator?  By being female, does that make the other the perpetrator?

Comment: i've read that question and answer and referred to such in my question. it still did not get to the heart of my question.

Comment: Dissatisfaction with existing answers is not an appropriate reason for asking the same question again.

Comment: it's not the same.

Comment: Then there's [this](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/18302/) as well. There are multiple answers to this question. Asking again isn't going to change what they are.

Comment: Yes, @Nij, i agree that this [newly referred question/answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/18302/laws-regarding-consensual-sex-and-intoxication) is about the same topic.  Yet there is no response about U.S. law.

Comment: All answers to the question you linked are by definition answers based in USA law. Your comment makes no sense.

Comment: *"Asking again isn't going to change what they are"*

Nij, try a little less condescension.  I explored the SE, found the other question that did not deal specifically with the question I had, I had not found the second question you referred to until you referred to it.

**Again, repeating there is another question, doesn't change what they are (or are not).**  And condescension gets you nowhere.

Comment: No Nij, the other question has answers only from Australian and U.K. law.  not one from the perspective of U.S. law.
Can you try to be less condescending and just maybe leave?

Comment: It's literally the first line of your question, and it's tagged united-states. You can't get more of a "response about U.S. law" than what is there. Perhaps it's condescension only because you haven't realised you don't know enough to know you don't know enough?

Comment: Let's **all** please remember to be nice. There's no need to respond to this unless commenting further on the question, or on comments that are _about the question_; comments about comments which are _not_ about the question need not be made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the other legally liable?

Yes, if found guilty by a court of law.

> How is it decided?

By triers of fact and law, generally in a court.

> What conditions must be met to hold one as the perpetrator and the other as the victim? By being first to cry "rape!", does that make the other the perpetrator? By being female, does that make the other the perpetrator?

Generally you first need to prove that a crime occurred in order for there to be, legally, a victim or a perpetrator. The victim is therefore the person who the perpetrator is found guilty of committing a crime against, or who suffers loss or harm, as a result of the perpetrator's crime. The perpetrator is the person who a legal instrument finds guilty, or who pleads guilty or confesses to a crime.

---

The question here is, in fact, answered by the first-mentioned link. If this is a site about laws and the law, then I think the questions raised in this question are perhaps more political and leading than we can answer. Historically, rape has *only* been defined in such a way that women could not be found guilty of the crime - penetrative sex could form the physical elements for rape only if carried out by a man against a woman.

So perhaps in the past, being female makes the other the perpetrator, because the law did not contemplate that a woman might be able to have sex with a man against his will.